# How to limit a pdf search to within certain pages

Tags: search, pdf-reader

How do you limit the search of a pdf to within a specific page range or specific chapter? I had an e-textbook and I want to search for glossary terms within the glossary, and not be redirected to another section of the book.
Explanations for how to do this in foxit reader would be nice, but if another reader can do this, please leave a comment.

Comment: What PDF-reader are you using?

Comment: @Yedric, obviously foxit reader

Comment: Doh! Don't know how I missed that!  Had to reread it twice before I saw it this time.  Thanks @m4573r

Comment: You could extract the glossary page to a separate PDF file and have that one open in a separate window as your own homemade index. I guess you don't have clickable page numbers anyway, so it would not come with any real drawbacks.